# Dúvida sobre o Controller no spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

Olá. Estou estudando o spring mvc e estou algumas dúvidas sobre o seu funcionamento. Uma delas é na parte do controller.

Quando eu preencho um formulário e solicito um método do controller, todos os parâmetros que eu recebo dentro desse método estão no request?
Nesse exemplo abaixo os parâmetros tarefa e result estão dentro do request e quando o método terminar serão repassados para o view (e se der erro na
validação de tarefa os erros serão guardados em result e será retornado para o formulario)?

```
@RequestMapping("adicionaTarefa")
public String adiciona(@Valid Tarefa tarefa, BindingResult result) {

    if(result.hasFieldErrors("descricao")) {
        return "tarefa/formulario";
    }   
    dao.adiciona(tarefa);
    return "tarefa/adicionada";
}
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vamos responder por partes**

*Quando eu preencho um formulário e solicito um método do controller, todos os parâmetros que eu recebo dentro desse método estão no request?*

**Sim**, os dados do formulário estão no body da sua requisição.

O [BindingResult](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) é avaliado na fase de validação, então ele não é passado no request, e sim incluído antes da requisição ser passada ao seu `@Controller` por meio do framework.

*Nesse exemplo abaixo os parâmetros tarefa e result estão dentro do request e quando o método terminar serão repassados para o view (e se der erro na validação de tarefa os erros serão guardados em result e será retornado para o formulario)?*

As coisas que estão indo para a tela podem ser encontradas dentro do objeto [Model](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html), que pode também ser incluído como parâmetro para sua visualização. O `BindingResult` irá conter os erros de validação sobre seu objeto passado no request, estas informações serão então repassadas para a view informada através do `Model`.

Você pode verificar o que está sendo retornado para a tela utilizando o método [Model.asMap()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html#asMap--) para verificar o que está sendo enviado para a tela.

Comment: Muito obrigado por esclarecer minhas dúvidas, nullptr. Sua explicação foi muito boa.